# How can I make this loop if the user inputs something other than yes or no or a number?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm guessing I need to use a while loop but I can't figure out where to put it so that it re-asks the question the user mistyped.I've tried putting while before and after the define statement but nothing happens when I input a non-valid answer.

```
import random
import string
    def random_pass(length):
    spec_char = input("Would you like special characters in your password? ")
    if spec_char == "yes":
        characters =  string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
        print("Your password is: ", password)
    elif spec_char == "no":
        characters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
        print("Your password is: ", characters)
    else:
        print("Please only type Yes or No")
char_length = int(input("How many characters would you like your password to be? "))
random_pass(char_length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modified your code a bit

```py
import random
import string
def random_pass(length):
    while True:
      spec_char = input("Would you like special characters in your password? ")
      if spec_char == "Yes":
          characters =  string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
          password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
          print("Your password is: ", password)
          return
      elif spec_char == "No":
          characters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
          print("Your password is: ", characters)
          return
      else:
          print("Please only type Yes or No")
char_length = int(input("How many characters would you like your password to be? "))
random_pass(char_length)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You use a while loop, and conditioning to break out of it.

```
while True:
    # Not encapsulating it with int() so it doesn't throw an error if it's not an integer
    char_length = input("How many characters would you like your password to be? ")

    if char_length.isdigit(): # built-in python method to see if a string has only digits
        char_length = int(char_length) # now convert it to integer knowing it's an integer
        break # Breaking the while loop.
    else:
        print("Invalid input")

random_pass(char_length)
```

For the other inputs, you obviously don't need to use .isdigit(), you just need to confirm it's the correct input such as "yes" or "no" and if not, then don't break the while loop.